# lvm storage full when torrented a large file, couldn't free up space

Tags: lvm

I started a torrent download to an lvm storage. The file was bigger then the free space on the storage, so I deleted it through the transmission interface, then I emptied the "Trash".
Now this is the output for df -h

```
Filesystem                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root  198G  187G  219M 100% /
```

As you can see, there should be roughly 10G of free space (size 198G, used 187G) but only 219M show up for available storage. I guess there was some corruption when I deleted the torrent before download.

The torrent size was 30G.

---

Somewhere I found that I should check open files.
I guess restart should solve the issue if this is the problem, but I still checked out the stuff I found on the internet.

- Biggest file in the output of `lsof +L1`

```
pulseaudi 1613 adam    6u   REG    0,1 67108864     0    2050 /memfd:pulseaudio (deleted)
```

I guess pulseaudio shouldn't be involved in this issue, and even if it is, if the size is given in bytes, this can't be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue had nothing to do with lvm. I had a google drive connected, it seems that it was the issue

Answer (score 0):

Nasty. You filled up the / partition. That is never going to end well.
The best thing I can suggest is that you force the deletion of the trash directory. Doing

rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/*

should do it. You may need a "sudo" on the front of that if you were playing around as root when you did this.

Comment: I've done that. I did again, just to double check and nothing.

Comment: Hmm. So where is your disk space going? I think thats what we need to understand. Can you do: 

sudo du -sh /*

This will take sometime but will give you a list of the top level directories in root and the disk space that they consume. It won't be fast if you have a number of other partitions mounted, and it will trawl the full directory tree. I am hoping that this will show where the disk space is being consumed. 

If you see one that looks way to high, say its /home. then do 

sudo du -sh /home/*

And keep drilling down.

Comment: One other thing? Do you have a file sharing tool such as dropbox, installed? One of my team had that on their desktop which has loads of disk space. They loaded it on to a laptop and filled the laptop drive up with hundreds of videos, films, photos etc which they really didn't want. The solution then was to use the Dropbox feature called selective sync. We disabled the sync of specific unwanted directories. The disk space came back but it took a couple of hours whilst dropbox sorted itself out. DONT be tempted to manually delete the files from your pc - this will delete them from Dropbox.

Comment: Omg, that was it -.- thank you!